# Adding a new JSON object in front of JSON array set

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Playing with nodeJs currently and have been trying to write new data into an existing JSON file, only to have problems with the format as well as getting the right data in. I want to get this new JSON obj to the FIRST of the array list. I did this by grabbing the first index ID, increment it, and tried using `unshift()` but it isn't adding the way I expected.

JSON file content `data.json`:

```
[
    {
      "id": 3,
      "content": "three"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "two"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
     "content": "one"
    } 
]
```

Code I wrote for new JSON obj I want to add:

```
var allJSON = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
var allj = JSON.parse(allJSON);
var lastId = parseInt(allj[0].id);
var newData = {
        id: ++lastId,
        content: "test"
    };

var allNewJSON = allj.unshift(JSON.stringify(newData));
// this yields a result of just the number "4" and erased everything else.
```

Comment: Read the docs for unshift here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can be found in the fine manual ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift#Return_value

Comment: Even aside from the problem with the value returned from `.unshift()`, why are you calling `JSON.stringify()` on the item you are trying to add to the array? The items already in your array are not JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is due to the way `unshift` works.

`unshift` is a function which returns the length of the updated array.

For example

```
> const a = [10, 20, 30];
> a.unshift(5);
4
```

That's right, the call to `unshift` *returns 4*, because the updated array has 4 elements.

Let's see the updated value of `a`:

```
> a
[5, 10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: I feel like using the term *"new array"* is incorrect. It's still the same old array, just bigger

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you! It is good to point that out in this case. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Array#unshift` does not create and return a new array; instead, it modifies the original array and returns its new *length*. In your case, this value would be `4`. I would suggest ignoring the return value of `unshift` and simply continuing your code using the `allj` variable, like so:

```
var allJSON = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
var allj = JSON.parse(allJSON);
var lastId = parseInt(allj[0].id);
var newData = {
        id: ++lastId,
        content: "test"
    };

allj.unshift(newData);
console.log(allj) // modified as desired!
```

Edit: As was mentioned in the comments above, you probably don't want to be calling `JSON.stringify` on the object `newData` before inserting it into your array. At this point you want to be working with JS objects rather than JSON strings.